# How to optimizing SQL Query with Cross Join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

How can I make this SQL query more efficient?  The CteFinal code shown below is a portion of my query which add up to 6 minutes to my query.  The cteMonth is shown below.  The cteDetail is another cte which pulls information directly from the database, and it takes less than a second to run.

What CteFinal is doing is creating missing fiscal period rows while including some of the column data from the row where f.FiscalPeriod=0.

*I cannot add, delete, or change any of the indexes on the tables, as this is a ERP database and I'm not allowed to make those type of changes.*

**CteFinal:**

```
SELECT      Account,Month, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(@Year as varchar(4)) + '-' + CAST(Month as VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + '01', 102) JEDate
        ,accountdesc,'' Description,'' JournalCode,NULL JournalNum,NULL JournalLine
        ,'' LegalNumber,'' CurrencyCode,0.00 DebitAmount,0.00 CreditAmount,fiscalcalendarid,company,bookid,SegValue2,SegValue1,SegValue3,SegValue4

FROM        cteDetail f
        CROSS JOIN cteMonths m

WHERE       f.FiscalPeriod=0 and not exists(select * from cteDetailADDCreatedZero x where x.Account=f.Account and x.FiscalPeriod=Month)
```

**CteMonth:**

```
cteMonths (Month) AS(
select 0 as Month
UNION select 1 as Month
UNION select 2 as Month
UNION select 3 as Month
UNION select 4 as Month
UNION select 5 as Month
UNION select 6 as Month
UNION select 7 as Month
UNION select 8 as Month
UNION select 9 as Month
UNION select 10 as Month
UNION select 11 as Month
UNION select 12 as Month)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What about doing a right join to cteMonth?

Comment: You could use `SET NOCOUNT ON` to reduce some network overhead, precede table names with `dbo.` to save a little security overhead, and if possible add the `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint to the tables. In your `AND NOT EXISTS` you could select just the primary key from your `cteDetailADDCreatedZero` table.

Comment: @Darth `WITH (NOLOCK)` will help prevent blocking but at the cost of potentially dirty data - and won't speed up this query on its own (only cases where updates are blocking reads). And the change you suggest to `NOT EXISTS` will have absolutely ZERO effect on anything.

Comment: Why is there a month 0 and a month 12? Do you really want 13 months represented? Why are you using a cross join? Do you really want 13 rows for every single row in the source? Otherwise can you tell us how to figure out what in `cteDetail` can tell us what month that data belongs to?

Comment: @Aaron The month 0 = the current year's opening balance and that row always will exist.  It is used to fill some of the columns in the other created rows. The matching is easy and has no affect on this query, but good question.

Comment: Showing the E/R diagram or the real tables will help. Also the existent indexes, and cardinality of tables.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the clarification, yeah if OP can't afford the possibility of dirty data then forget that idea. I'd thought some tiny bit less work would be needed to just grab a single column instead of doing a `SELECT *` but now that I think about it, maybe the SQL optimizer would do this and make such redundant?

Comment: @Darth SQL Server is smart enough to know that `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` do not return data, so it actually ignores the column list altogether. You can say `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1/0 FROM dbo.wherever)` and it won't complain. Absolutely no difference to performance no matter what you put in there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly more efficient way to generate the 12 months of a given year (even more efficient if you have [your own Numbers table](http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-1)):

```
DECLARE @year INT = 2013;

;WITH cteMonths([Month],AsDate) AS
(
  SELECT n-1,DATEADD(YEAR, @Year-1900, DATEADD(MONTH,n-1,0)) FROM (
    SELECT TOP (13) RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects
  ) AS c(n)
)
SELECT [Month], AsDate FROM cteMonths;
```

So now, you can say:

```
;WITH cteMonths([Month],AsDate) AS
(
  SELECT n,DATEADD(YEAR, @Year-1900, DATEADD(MONTH,n-1,0)) FROM (
    SELECT TOP (13) RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects
  ) AS c(n)
), 
cteDetail AS 
(
  ...no idea what is here...
),
cteDetailADDCreatedZero AS
(
  ...no idea what is here...
)
SELECT f.Account, m.[Month], JEDate = m.AsDate, f.accountdesc, Description = '',
  JournalCode = '', JournalNum = NULL, JournalLine = NULL, LegalNumber = '', 
  CurrencyCode = '', DebitAmount = 0.00, CreditAmount = 0.00, f.fiscalcalendarid, 
  f.company, f.bookid, f.SegValue2, f.SegValue1, f.SegValue3, f.SegValue4
FROM cteMonths AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN cteDetail AS f
ON ... some clause I am not clear on ...  
WHERE f.FiscalPeriod = 0 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM cteDetailADDCreatedZero AS x 
  WHERE x.Account = f.Account 
  AND x.FiscalPeriod = m.[Month]
);
```

I suspect this won't solve your problem though: it is likely that this is forcing an entire table scan on either whatever tables are mentioned in `cteDetail` or `cteDetailADDCreatedZero` or both. You should inspect the actual execution plan for this query and see if there are any scans or other expensive operations that could guide you towards better indexing. It also might just be that you have a bunch of inefficient CTEs stacked up together - we can't really help with that unless you show everything. CTEs are like views - if you start stacking them up on top of each other, you really limit the optimizer's ability to generate an efficient plan for you. At some point it will just throw its hands in the air...

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is **to physicalize the SQL View** (if it the query is a view). Sometimes views with complex queries are slow.